# How to find the value of h and k in limit without L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

Given that 
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow -2^-}\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x+h}+k} = 6
$$
Find the value of h and k.

I have tried my best but the limit always 
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow -2^-}\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{h-2} = 0
$$

Comment: @Mathematician42 I think he means L'Hospital Theorem

Comment: Hmm sorry I'm just a self-studying beginner

Comment: It's L'Hôpital's rule, not Ho**s**pital.

Comment: L'Hospital spelt his name with an S. The spelling with a circumflex comes from subsequent developments in French orthography where a silent letter S after a vowel was omitted, and the omission noted by a circumflex. @Mathematician42

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The second edition of the “Analyse des infiniments petis” bears the author's name (the first edition didn't) spelled as *M. le marquis* de l'Hôpital. https://books.google.it/books?id=YIBuClYFqyIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=l%27analyse+de+l%27infiniment+petit+l%27hopital&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQo8vthtXZAhWFyRQKHWU3BQoQ6AEIOzAC#v=onepage&q=l'analyse%20de%20l'infiniment%20petit%20l'hopital&f=false

Comment: @Tex Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that 
$$
\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x+h}+k} = \frac{x+2}{x+h-k^2}(\sqrt{x+h}-k)
$$
As $x\to -2$, this has a nonzero limit only if $h-k^2=2$. The limit is then $\sqrt{-2+h}-k$ so $(6+k)^2=-2+h$. The only solution is $k=-3$, $h=11$.

Comment: How can you get that k = -3 and h = 11 from (6+k)² = -2+h

Comment: @Tex You're forgetting that we also have $h-k^2=2$.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!!! Erm..Last question , is my question is too "low class"?

Comment: @Tex At least in principle, we do not care about the mathematical level of a question, except that research level questions are better over on mathoverflow.com. We do, however, care about question _quality_, but that has nothing to do with the problem itself but rather how you present it to us: where you got the problem from, why you want the answer, and explicitly what you have tried to solve it. "I have tried a lot of things but they didn't work" is not so good, "I tried simplifying the fraction by 3 but only got nonsense" is better. Including the actual nonsense you got would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Since the numerator vanishes at $-2$, in order that the limit is $6$ also the denominator must vanish at $-2$; now
$$
\sqrt{-2+h}+k=0
$$
implies $k\le0$ and $-2+h=k^2$. Therefore $h=k^2+2$. Now it's just rationalizing: for $x\ne-2$,
$$
\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x+2+k^2}+k}=
\frac{x+2}{x+2}(\sqrt{x+2+k^2}-k)=\sqrt{x+2+k^2}-k
$$
so you get $\sqrt{k^2}-k=6$.

Can you finish? Remember that $k\le0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=y-2$ with $y \to 0$ then

$$\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x+h}+k}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{y-2+h}+k}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{h-2}\sqrt{1+\frac{y}{h-2}}+k}\sim \frac{y}{\sqrt{h-2}\left(1+\frac{y}{2(h-2)}\right)+k}=\frac{2y(h-2)}{2(h-2)\sqrt{h-2}+y\sqrt{h-2}+2k(h-2)}$$

and this tends to $6$ if and only if

- $2(h-2)\sqrt{h-2}+2k(h-2)=0$
- $\frac{2(h-2)}{\sqrt{h-2}}=2\sqrt{h-2}=6\implies h=11$

and then

- $2(11-2)\sqrt{11-2}+2k(11-2)=54+18k=0\implies k=-3$

Note that for

$\sqrt{1+\frac{y}{h-2}}\sim 1+\frac{y}{2(h-2)}$

we have used the binomial expansion for $x\to 0 \implies (1+x)^a\sim 1+ax$.